# Ho to do polygon search for a coordinate in Neo4j 3.0.0

Tags: neo4j

How to define multiple geo polygons in Neo4j?

how to find out a geo coordinate belong to which polygon / polygons stored in neo4j?

I am new to Neo4j so please help me out on this.

and please suggest (Java + Neo4j ) OR (Nodejs + Neo4j) ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [neo4j-spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial). It allows you to assign geometries with your nodes and builds up r-tree structures to do polygon search.

Note that there not yet a released version for 3.0, but master branch works nicely already. So build it from source yourself for now.